# High proportion of zero values and PCA

Tags: pca, data-transformation, skewness, zero-inflation

My aim is to perform PCA since I have 76 variables in my dataset. Problem is that most of my variables are highly skewed as you can see in the histogram below.

[image]

These variables are proportions derived from count data. For example:

```
ID  count_of_purchases count_of_products Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun Product1 Product2 Product3
1            16                43         7   1   2   3   2   0   1     17      14       12
2            2                 11         1   0   1   0   0   0   0      6       0        5  
3            92                112       32  18   2  18  14   3   7     27      47       38
4            31                104        9   1  15   3   3   0   0     41      13       50
5            11                15         2   3   2   4   0   0   0     3        3        5
```

As you can see, sum of the day counts corresponds to count_of_purchases and the same goes for count_of_products. I transformed this table to proportions.

[image]

Do I need to perform some other kind of transformation of the variables than just scaling in order to prevent the PCA from skewed results? Or is there any better choice than PCA for this kind of data? Thank you for the answers.

Comment: You could try a distance-based technique such as NMDS (non-metric multidimensional scaling). The `vegan` package has great support for this.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What about the zero values in the dataset? Would you recommend some transformation?

Comment: Stefan, can you advice what kind of distance for NMDS should I use for my sparse data?

Comment: No you don't need to transform zeros in NMDS. I would try out various distances and see how this changes results. Here is a good tutorial: http://geoffreyzahn.com/nmds-example/

Comment: Hi Stefan, now for clustering...what would be the appropriate distance and method for clustering my data?